# Altering classes using CSS with spaces in the class name

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I alter a class in CSS that has spaces in the class name?

I want to alter this class:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

how do I select it in the CSS file?

```
.navbar-collapse collapse{

}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There are no spaces in classes.   Possible naming conventions are: foo-bar(hyphen), fooBar(camelCased), foo_bar (snake case), or just foobar.

Given:

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

CSS Target:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse
```

The space the way you wrote it would say that collapse is a child node, so select the div collapse that is the child of navbar-collapse, which markup would resemble:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse">
    <div class="collapse">foo</div>
 </div>
```

Pro's use different naming conventions to denote different THINGS. Everyteam is different, but usually around this:

1. I like to use hyphens for my css classes: foo-bar
2. Snake_case for ids: #foo_bar
3. I never camel case css, but somepeople do it to signify this class is written from Javascript.
4. If one of my devs wrote a two word css class key, he'd be made fun of.

Comment: The way it's written in the question would actually refer to a non-existent element, `collapse`, rather than a div with a class of collapse.

Comment: @NathanDawson didn't i cover that with  <div class="navbar-collapse"><div class="collapse">foo</div></div>

Comment: Not quite. Minor detail but you put `<div class="collapse">` (a div with an element of collapse). The way it's written would actually mean an element, `collapse` (non-existent of course). E.g. `<div class="navbar-collapse"><collapse>`

Answer (score 1):

The spaces you see mean the div element has multiple classes rather than a space in the class name.

You could target this element in your CSS with either `.navbar-collapse` or `.collapse`.

If you wanted to only affect elements with both classes you would use `.navbar-collapse.collapse`.

```
.navbar-collapse {
  // CSS for elements with a class of 'navbar-collapse'.
}

.collapse {
  // CSS for elements with a class of 'collapse'.
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  // CSS for elements with a class of both 'navbar-collapse' and 'collapse'.
}
```

Comment: This is the proper target, but doesn't address what he's trying to learn.